# Android Activity not Responding

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 3 activities in my app and when user press next button, next activity is shown to user, Now everything works fine except when it reaches the last activity i.e. when user presses next on 2nd last activity, an error message is shown that app has stopped working and there is no error in LogCat, following is the .java file of my Final Activity

```
package com.example.first;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

public class FinalActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView name,address,phone,email,dob,matg,mati,interg,interi,graddeg,gradi,cgpa,skills;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_final);
        name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.fname);
        address=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.faddress);
        phone=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.fphone);
        email=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.femail);
        dob=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.fdob);
        matg=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.matricgrade);
        mati=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.matricinst);
        interg=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.intergrade);
        interi=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.interinst);
        graddeg=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.graddegree);
        cgpa=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.gradcgpa);
        skills=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.iskills);
        Intent in=getIntent();
        UserBO bo=new UserBO();
        bo.name=in.getStringExtra("name");
        bo.address=in.getStringExtra("address");
        bo.email=in.getStringExtra("email");
        bo.phone=in.getStringExtra("phone");
        bo.dob=in.getStringExtra("dob");
        bo.mg=in.getStringExtra("mgrade");
        bo.mi=in.getStringExtra("minst");
        bo.ig=in.getStringExtra("igrade");
        bo.ii=in.getStringExtra("iinst");
        bo.gg=in.getStringExtra("gdeg");
        bo.gi=in.getStringExtra("ginst");
        bo.cgpa=in.getStringExtra("cgpa");
        bo.skills=in.getStringExtra("skills");
        name.setText("Name : "+bo.name);
        address.setText("Address : "+bo.address);
        email.setText("Email : "+bo.email);
        phone.setText("Phone : "+bo.phone);
        dob.setText("DOB : "+bo.dob);
        matg.setText("Matric Grade : "+bo.mg);
        mati.setText("Institution : "+bo.mi);
        interg.setText("Inter Grade : "+bo.ig);
        interi.setText("Institution : "+bo.ii);
        graddeg.setText("Graduation Degree : "+bo.gg);
        gradi.setText("Institution : "+bo.gi);
        skills.setText("Skills : "+bo.skills);


    }



}
```

Here is the xml file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.first.FinalActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/faddress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fphone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/femail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fdob"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/matricgrade"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/matricinst"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/intergrade"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/interinst"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/graddegree"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gradinst"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gradcgpa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/iskills"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />
        <TextView

       android:id="@+id/hobbies"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here i'm calling the final activity

```
package com.example.first;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.os.Build;

public class Activity2 extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button next3;
    EditText s1,s2,s3,s4,s5;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity2);
        next3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.next3);
        s1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.sk1);
        s2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.sk2);
        s3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.sk3);
        s4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.sk4);
        s5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.sk5);
         next3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent in=getIntent();
                    UserBO bo=new UserBO();
                    bo.name=in.getStringExtra("name");
                    bo.address=in.getStringExtra("address");
                    bo.email=in.getStringExtra("email");
                    bo.phone=in.getStringExtra("phone");
                    bo.dob=in.getStringExtra("dob");
                    bo.mg=in.getStringExtra("mgrade");
                    bo.mi=in.getStringExtra("minst");
                    bo.ig=in.getStringExtra("igrade");
                    bo.ii=in.getStringExtra("iinst");
                    bo.gg=in.getStringExtra("gdeg");
                    bo.gi=in.getStringExtra("ginst");
                    bo.cgpa=in.getStringExtra("cgpa");
                    bo.skills+=s1.getText().toString()+","+s1.getText().toString()+","+s2.getText().toString()+","+s3.getText().toString()+","+s4.getText().toString()+","+s5.getText().toString();
                    Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FinalActivity.class);//this,same
                    System.out.println(bo.name);
                    i.putExtra("name", bo.name);
                    i.putExtra("address", bo.address);
                    i.putExtra("email", bo.email);
                    i.putExtra("phone", bo.phone);
                    i.putExtra("dob", bo.dob);
                    i.putExtra("mgrade", bo.mg);
                    i.putExtra("minst", bo.mi);
                    i.putExtra("igrade", bo.ig);
                    i.putExtra("iinst", bo.ii);
                    i.putExtra("gdeg", bo.gg);
                    i.putExtra("ginst", bo.gi);
                    i.putExtra("cgpa", bo.cgpa);
                    i.putExtra("skills", bo.skills);



                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });



    }
```

Here is Activity1

```
package com.example.first;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.os.Build;

public class Activity1 extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button next2;
    EditText matGrade,matInst,iGrade,iInst,gDegree,gInst,gCgpa;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity1);
         next2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.next2);
            matGrade=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mgrade);
            matInst=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.minst);
            iGrade=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.igrade);
            iInst=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.iinst);
            gDegree=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.gdegree);
            gInst=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ginst);
            gCgpa=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.cgpa);
            next2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent in=getIntent();
                    UserBO bo=new UserBO();
                    bo.name=in.getStringExtra("name");
                    bo.address=in.getStringExtra("address");
                    bo.email=in.getStringExtra("email");
                    bo.phone=in.getStringExtra("phone");
                    bo.dob=in.getStringExtra("dob");
                    bo.mg=matGrade.getText().toString();
                    bo.mi=matGrade.getText().toString();
                    bo.ig=iGrade.getText().toString();
                    bo.ii=iGrade.getText().toString();
                    bo.gg=gDegree.getText().toString();
                    bo.gi=gDegree.getText().toString();
                    bo.cgpa=gDegree.getText().toString();

                    Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Activity2.class);//this,same
                    i.putExtra("name", bo.name);
                    i.putExtra("address", bo.address);
                    i.putExtra("email", bo.email);
                    i.putExtra("phone", bo.phone);
                    i.putExtra("dob", bo.dob);
                    i.putExtra("mgrade", bo.mg);
                    i.putExtra("minst", bo.mi);
                    i.putExtra("igrade", bo.ig);
                    i.putExtra("iinst", bo.ii);
                    i.putExtra("gdeg", bo.gg);
                    i.putExtra("ginst", bo.gi);
                    i.putExtra("cgpa", bo.cgpa);




                    startActivity(i);

                }

    });




}
}
```

Here is the main Activity

```
package com.example.first;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {





    Button next1;
    EditText name,address,email,phone,date;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        next1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.next1);
        name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        address=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.address);
        email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        phone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone);
        date=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.date);



        next1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                UserBO bo=new UserBO();
                bo.name=name.getText().toString();
                bo.address=address.getText().toString();
                bo.email=email.getText().toString();
                bo.phone=phone.getText().toString();
                bo.dob=date.getText().toString();
                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Activity1.class);//this,same
                i.putExtra("name", bo.name);
                i.putExtra("address", bo.address);
                i.putExtra("email", bo.email);
                i.putExtra("phone", bo.phone);
                i.putExtra("dob", bo.dob);




                startActivity(i);

            }
        });








    }




}
```

Please help me find the mistake

Comment: logcat will be hehlpfull

Comment: where is the activity1 ?

Comment: I've edited post, activity1 has been added as well as main activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have null pointer exception. Maybe one of your controls is missed in your xml layout. For example you are finding "next1" in your code and using its `setOnClickListener` method while it is not defined in you xml layout so its object is null.

I recommend you put the content of `onCreate` method in a `try-catch` and debug your application.

Comment: next1 is there in my main activity's xml file

Comment: It was an example. Use try-catch